# CSS animation lag in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a gallery built with HTML & CSS. Each item in the gallery should be clickable, and on:hover should display a brief description of what that specific item contains. The whole effect is based on what Apple has on it's [Newsroom site](http://apple.com/newsroom/).

The code I have works perfect on both Firefox and Chrome, but I keep getting lags in Safari (v12).

I have the following Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".item").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".description_container").css("height", "auto").css("margin", "0 20px 20px 20px");
        $(this).find(".description").css("opacity", "1");
        $(this).find("img").css("opacity", "0.5");
        $(this).find("video").css("opacity", "0.5");
        $(this).css("box-shadow","0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15)").css("cursor","pointer");
      }, function(){
        $(this).css("box-shadow","0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0)").css("cursor","default");
        $(this).find("img").css("opacity", "1");
        $(this).find("video").css("opacity", "1");
        $(this).find(".description_container").css("height", "0px").css("margin", "0 20px");
        $(this).find(".description").css("opacity", "0");
      });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="placeholder.png">
          <!-- The whole item is a link -->
          <a href="https://example.com/" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width:100%; height:100%;">
          <div class="content">
          <p class="tags"><span class="gato">#</span>
          <span class="tag">Sample tag 1</span>
          <span class="tag">Sample tag 2</span>
          <!-- Title -->
          <h2>This is an Item's Title!</h2>
          <!-- Date -->
          <p class="date">December 2018</p>
          <!-- Description -->
          <div class="description_container">
          <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div></div></a></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
    * {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
      -moz-transition:    all 0.2s ease;
      -ms-transition:     all 0.2s ease;
      -o-transition:      all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .gallery {
      margin: 60px auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }

    .item {
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 4px;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 105px;
      border-bottom: solid #D9E7F6 2px;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
      background-color: black;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .item img {
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      -webkit-user-drag: none;
      -khtml-user-drag: none;
      -moz-user-drag: none;
      -o-user-drag: none;
      user-drag: none;
    }

    .item .content {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .item .tags {
      margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    }

    .item .tags .gato {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #9FB8D8;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .item .tags .tag {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #0071FF;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .item h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: black;
      margin: 5px 20px;
    }

    .item .date {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #9B9B9B;
      margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    .item .description {
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #9B9B9B;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .item .description_container {
      position: relative;
      height: 0px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

- [Video] See it in [Chrome](https://youtu.be/kd1wXd95czs).
- [Video] See it in [Safari](https://youtu.be/3Nefhp9BuEE).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you want to get a super smooth effect you must play with `transform` (`rotate`, `scale`, `translate`, `matrix`, `skew`...), opacity properties only. You should avoid as possible to animate height and margin as you did. Because those properties [cause repaints and/or reflow on the page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/). Here is another good link that give more details about [which properties you should use](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) in order to get a 60fps animation.

> We’re going to cut straight to the chase. Modern browsers can animate four things really cheaply: position, scale, rotation and opacity. If you animate anything else, it’s at your own risk, and the chances are you’re not going to hit a silky smooth 60fps.

Also you should avoid using JS or jQuery to animate or select elements when CSS can do the job right. Here, your effect can be achieved only by using `:hover` pseudo-class. Actually, Apple (on the page you gave) creates its animation with CSS only -> `:hover`. jQuery, may cause long depth analysis in the DOM and insert some junks into the 60fps animation you desire. in your code you have added a lot of js in order to replicate a behavior that css can achieve alone in a very very fast way. The common way to do it is : If the parent element is hovered, update all classes that covers its children elements **in your CSS stylesheet (not Js)**.

This is a simple exemple:

```
.parent-el {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child-el-1 {
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: transform .4s ease;
}
.child-el-2 {
  transform:rotate(0);
  transition: transform .4s ease;
}

.parent-el:hover .child-el-1 {
  transform: translate3D(100px,0,0);
}
.parent-el:hover .child-el-2 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

In your case, that could be:

```
.item { box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0); ...} // A better approach way to achieve it, is to use :after/:before pseudo element that contains box-shadow that you will animate with opacity property (0-1).
.item:hover { box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); ... }

.container { opacity: 0; ...}
.item:hover .container { opacity: 1; ...}

.item img, .item video{ opacity: 1; ...}
.item:hover img, .item:hover video{ opacity: .5; ...}

...
```

And don't forget to set the `transition` property for each (Also, `*` selector could be tricky to deal with in future for your code).

To finish, you can try to add the `will-change` [property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/) that can help improving performance in animation (need to be used in moderation).

There are a lot of thing to say/write about fps performance on the web but I'm sure that those short advices will help you in your web animation performance quest.

Comment: Just changed all :hover effects to CSS (using the same problematic height and margin changes) and even though they still aren't as smooth as Chrome, they definitely perform a lot better!

I've been reading a lot about transform: properties, but can't seem to find a way to achieve the same effect I have… Looked at the code at Apple's site too, but looks like they have a pre-set transformY px for :hover, so I can't replicate that since my content would be a bit more dynamic. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Yes Chrome is often (always ?) speeder than other browsers. Maybe you can pre-calculate dynamically  transformY with JS ? I think that could be a good idea. Also have you tried to use will-change properties ? The way to improve smoothness is to deal with transform/opacity properties, avoid dee css depth and avoid using too much JS when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that may happen because you use find() alot ,

> This method traverse downwards along descendants of DOM elements, all
>   the way down to the last descendant

use children() to access chelidren directly or querySelector() or any other approach.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more inefficient?, because .children() only looks for the direct child of an element, so I would have to .find() the parent element anyway

Comment: Actually that's right, but I think you should avoid both of them in that case and use CSS method only to do the job. You don't need js at all to achieve your effect here and `hover` pseudo-class is more appropriate and native to avoid junks if you use it with a good approach.